# Key-Value observe any NSOperationQueue variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I'm using KVO to observe changes in my `NSOperationQueue` variable in order to show/hide `[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible`, this way:

```
[_operationQueue addObserver:self
                      forKeyPath:@"operationCount"
                         options:0
                         context:NULL];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSOperationQueue class]]) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"operationCount"]) {
            if ([(NSOperationQueue *)object operationCount] == 0) {
                if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible) {
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                }
            }
            else if ([(NSOperationQueue *)object operationCount] > 0) {
                if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible) {
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

I thought about doing a global observing for any instance of NSOperationQueue - new/main/current.

I can observe current and main, but e.g. what if I'm creating a few instances of `NSOperationQueue` or what if I'm creating a few new ones with my subclassed `NSURLConnection` (`NSURLConnectionSSL` if it matters) how can I observe all of them?

What if I want to observe in entire program and make it globally and not in a single class?

Comment: addObserver and removeObserver are like retain/release in the pre-ARC days.  You have to decide what object in your program is going to own all those addObserver calls and figure how to remove them when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Do you want to observer queues no matter where they're created? Or are all of them properties of the observing class (or accessible by the observing class)?

Comment: I want to observe all queues no matter where they're created.